# printing a word per line

Tags: c, string, line

I need to write a program that prints its input one word per line. Here's what I got so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main(){
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        if (c != ' ' || c!='\n' || c!='\t')
            printf("%c", c);
        else 
            printf("\n");
    }
}
```

The logic is pretty simple. I check to see if the input is not a newline, tab or space, and in that case it prints it, otherwise prints a newline.

When I run it, I get results like this:

```
input-->  This is
output--> This is
```

It prints the whole thing. What goes wrong here?

Comment: Take a look at `putchar`. (`printf` is *not* the only way to print things, and sometimes not the best either.) Also, ask yourself what happens when words have more than one space between them.

Comment: You might want to check out `scanf` (or `fscanf`) for input.  It knows how to skip whitespace and give you the next word.

Comment: Suggest `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){ if (!isspace(c)) { printf("%c", c); else ...`

Comment: the layout of a main function is: int main() { ... return(0); }  all the warnings need to be enabled when compiling/linking.  (warnings need to be corrected)

Comment: this line: 'if (c != ' ' || c!='\n' || c!='\t')' should be: 'if (c != ' ' && c!='\n' && c!='\t')'  the reason for the change..  if any one of those comparisons is 'true' then the char is printed.  By using '&&', than all the comparisons must be 'tgrue' to print the char.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`if (c != ' ' || c!='\n' || c!='\t')`
This will never be false.

Perhaps you meant:
`if (c != ' ' && c!='\n' && c!='\t')`

Answer (score 1):

instead of using printf try putchar, also as per above comments, you should use && instead of ||.

here is my code-

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    int c, nw;                  /* nw for word & c for character*/

    while ( ( c = getchar() ) != EOF ){

    if ( c != ' ' && c != '\n' && c != '\t')
    nw = c;
    else {
        nw = '\n';
    }

    putchar (nw);

    }

}
```

this code will give you the desired output

Answer (score 0):

you can use if you want the `strtok` function in `string.h` library which can cut the input into many words by providing a delimiter.

Here is a perfect code commented which can fit to your needs

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char line[1000]=""; // the line that you will enter in the input
    printf("Input the line:\n>>");
    scanf("%[^\n]",line); // read the line till the you hit enter button
    char *p=strtok(line," !#$%&'()*+,-./'"); // cut the line into words 
    // delimiter here are punctuation characters  (blank)!#$%&'()*+,-./'

    printf("\nThese are the words written in the line :\n");
    printf("----------------------------------------\n");
    while (p!=NULL) // a loop to extract the words one by one 
    {
        printf("%s\n",p); // print each word
        p=strtok(NULL," !#$%&'()*+,-./'"); // repeat till p is null 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If we execute the code above we will get

```
Input the line:
>>hello every body how are you !

These are the words written in the line :
----------------------------------------
hello
every
body
how
are
you
```

Comment: If user enters `"\n"`, `line` is not initialized and code continues with undefined behavior.

Comment: source of the undefined behavior please !

Comment: I said it right there: "If user enters "\n", line is not initialized ".  With `line` in an undefined state, `strtok(line...` results in UB.  What do you think happens to `line` when user enters `"\n"`?

Comment: it will contain garbage and please be more specific "\n" and ctrl-d are two different things ! Thanks for the info ! you are totatlly right !

Comment: Better to use `fgets()`.  As you are tokening, the typical trailing `'\n'` brought in with `fgets()` vs. `scanf("%[^\n]"...` will not be an issue.  Plus code then well handles input `"\n"` and long inputs.

Comment: `fgets` will stop reading at every `\n` (but will be included) we can change `scanf` to support many lines by adding a simple `\n` to the format ... this will be another issue !!  I wanted to make the code simple ! that's why ! :)

Comment: "we can change scanf to support many lines by adding a simple \n to the format"  --> No that will not work.  How do you add `'\n'` to everything but `'\n'` as in `"%[^\n]"`?  In effect, you want to stop on nothing?

Comment: a line 'could' be more than 999 characters.  suggest using the getline() function.

Comment: @chux This is the line `(__COUNTER__)?:scanf("\n%[^\n]",line);scanf("%[^\n]",line);` put the code written as an answer in a loop and change the simple`scanf` line with the one in this comment ! Enjoy ! 1-1 final score :P ! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
suggest the code implement a state machine, 
where there are two states, in-a-word and not-in-a-word.  
Also, there are numerous other characters that could be read 
(I.E. ',' '.' '?' etc) that need to be check for. 

the general logic:

state = not-in-a-word
output '\n'

get first char
loop until eof
    if char is in range a...z or in range A...Z
    then 
        output char
        state = in-a-word
    else if state == in-a-word
    then
         output '\n'
         state = not-in-a-word
    else
         do nothing
    end if
    get next char
end loop

output '\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simple solution would be like

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    int c;
    while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
    {
        if(c==' ' || c=='\t' || c=='\b')
        {
            printf("\n");
            while(c==' ' || c=='\t' || c=='\b')
            c=getchar();
        }
        if(c!=EOF)
        putchar(c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```